# Bison & Flex cmake configuration

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I have Makefile file which manage building of my bison&flex&c++ project:

```
CFLAGS = -g
all:      cppcalc
cppcalc:    cppcalc.lex.o cppcalc.tab.o
    c++ -g -o $@ cppcalc.tab.o cppcalc.lex.o -lm
cppcalc.lex.o: cppcalc.lex.c cppcalc.tab.hh cppcalc-ctx.hh
    c++ -c $<
cppcalc.tab.o: cppcalc.tab.cc cppcalc-ctx.hh klasa.hh
cppcalc.lex.c: cppcalc.l
    flex -ocppcalc.lex.c cppcalc.l
cppcalc.tab.cc cppcalc.tab.hh: cppcalc.yy
    bison -vd cppcalc.yy
```

This works all right. I would like to convert this think to cmake. Right now I wrote something like this below, but I am getting errors after I typed *make* and I have no idea what is wrong:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(BISON)
find_package(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(MyParser cppcalc.yy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppcalc.tab.cc COMPILE_FLAGS -vd)
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner cppcalc.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppcalc.lex.c)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(MyScanner MyParser)

 include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
 add_executable(Foo
    ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS}
    cppcalc-ctx.hh
    klasa.hh
 )
```

[image: output]

Comment: Check that file `cppcalc-ctx.hh` exists. As for `klasa.hh`, it probably is in your source directory, so you should issue appropriate `include_directories()` command.

Comment: Turn on verbose build output (can cmake do that?) and see what compilation command is actually being run (to see what flags are, or aren't, being passed).

Comment: @EtanReisner For `make` it would be `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: @usr1234567 For `cmake` having output to Makefiles you mean? (Because `make` itself doesn't have that sort of concept.)

Comment: @EtanReisner That's a shell variable evaluated by the Makefile generated from CMake.

Comment: @usr1234567 So that's "Yes, for makefiles generated by cmake" then, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(BISON 2.4.1)
find_package(FLEX 2.5.35)

BISON_TARGET(MyParser cppcalc.yy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cppcalc.tab.cpp)
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner cppcalc.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.cpp)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(MyScanner MyParser)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(Calc
  ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS}
  ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS}
)
```